# What color is smurf blood?

Tags: biology, smurfs

Is it known whether smurf blood is red or blue?

I checked [the UNICEF ad](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qa8MjjMajEA) (an ad where the Smurf village was annihilated by warplanes), but couldn't spot any blood in the ad.

Comment: +17 in 8 hours?  What the devil goes on in all your minds?!  (+1)

Comment: @Izkata - No no no. You're doing it wrong. You're supposed to say "What Smurferry is this!"

Comment: @SystemDown The force of Captain Picard is stronger in me  ;)

Comment: @Izkata I'm guessing the question got on Twitter.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Officially, the color of smurfs blood is not known, but there is enough information to conclude that they have red blood.

As a comic targeted to young children, any display of blood is carefully avoided. As an example, any harm is displayed as dark marks:

[image: hit smurf]

The real reason why their skin is blue is unknown. Some have supposed it's because their blood is blue, but it might be caused by pigmentation.

I thought I remembered one of them blushing because of Smurfette, or maybe it was her? Anyway, I did not find any proof.

The only thing that might indicate they have red blood is that their tongues are red, which is [caused by hemoglobin on mammalian](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5298/are-tongues-red-because-they-contain-blood). However, Smurfs are not mammalian, but it's still a good indication of their blood color.

[image: yawn!]

---

## Update :

I found a blushing Smurf [here (french site)](http://www.bdoubliees.com/journalspirou/sfigures6/schtroumpfs/combien.htm), it's the #90, with the legend "*90 Schtroumpf rougissant*," which translates to "blushing Smurf". The image was taken from  number 1354 of [Spirou magazine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirou_%28magazine%29) (published in 1964). It is canon as it has [Peyo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peyo)'s signature  :

[image: Schtroumpf rougissant]

As you see, the blushing Smurf is purple. So red blood + blue skin = purple Smurf.

---

## Update 2 :

As [kylusD indicated on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/19byyo/til_there_is_actual_canon_proof_that_smurf_blood/c8msndg), there is [an episode (Smurfette's Rose)](http://smurfs.wikia.com/wiki/Smurfette%27s_Rose) were Smurfette wishes to Mother Nature for a Blue Rose, but it made her turn white. However, she pricks her finger to break the spell:

[image: Smurfette prick her finger]

Her blood was red!

Comment: Truly awesome answer. Is this canon?

Comment: @AliAfshar As I said, the last image is signed by Peyo, the creator of *The Smurfs*. It cannot be more Canon.

Comment: Except that _rougissant_ means _reddened_. Not necessarily from blushing!

Comment: @MrLister French is my first language, you could trust me on this one. I agree that may be a pun, but look at his face, he his clearly embarrassed. Anyway, the physical reaction that caused the poor Smurf to turn purple is a flooding of blood on his face.

Comment: Wow. An actual canon answer! Smurfy!

Comment: Smurftastic answer

Comment: Best answer I could hope for short of asking Gargamel! Your answer has prompted me to ask on biology if human tongues are red [because of blood](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5298/are-tongues-red-because-they-contain-blood), but the blushing is good evidence as well.

Comment: smurfalicious answer.

Comment: also, the strong smurf has a heart tattoo, and the heart is red colored

Comment: @riffraff: which simply raises another question: what color was the tattoo ink?

Comment: @riffraff As well as: why haven't we seen tattoo artist smurf?

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't use Smurfette as the example for all Smurfs since she was created by Gargamel.

Comment: @LuckySmurf - I'm pretty sure that Papa Smurf says something in the cartoons about making her a "real smurf".

Comment: @Richard: Why can I not read your comment without hearing Papa Smurf proudly proclaim that he's "going to make Smurfette a woman tonight, aw yeah..."?

Comment: @seanduggan - Giggity

Comment: Smurfette is not a true smurf. She was created by Gargomyle with magic, and not born under a blue moon. So it's stands to reason she may bleed another color than smurfs born under the blue moon.